# List through has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this db schema

```
class User
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :biller
end

class Biller
  has_many :accounts
end
```

How to get a list of billers of the user?

```
billers = user.?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add has_many association with thorough option:

```
class User
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :billers, through: :accounts 
end

class Account
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :biller
end

class Biller
  has_many :accounts
end
```

And use it like follow:

```
billers = user.billers
```

More information see in the Active Record [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

Comment: Make sure to add `:user_id` and `:biller_id` to the Accounts table in your database.

Comment: if they weren't already there, his existing classes wouldn't work.